# Can't install mysql2 for rails 3 on Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can't install mysql2 without an error message. I've tried every way I can think of including using devkit.

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-include=c:/xampp/mysql/inclu
de --with-mysql-lib=c:/xampp/mysql/lib --with-mysql-config=c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my
sql_config

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-include=c:/xampp/
mysql/include --with-mysql-lib=c:/xampp/mysql/lib --with-mysql-config=c:/xampp/m
ysql/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Make sure your library points to /lib/opt and not just /lib

Comment: You should make your question a real question, and if you answered it yourself, do it jeopardy style: question first, then a separate answer.

Comment: Please do not use pseudo-tags like `[solved]` in your question title.  If you have solved your own problem, please post the solution as an answer, then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

### Using MySQL with Rails 3 on Windows

- **Install railsinstaller** -> *www.railsinstaller.org* (I installed it to c:\Rails)
- **Install MySQL** (I used MySQL 5.5) -> *dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/*

> **--- for mySQL installation ---**
>   
>  If you dont already have **these two files** installed you might need them to get your MySQL going
>   vcredist_x86.exe -> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555
>   dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe -> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718
>   
>   Use default install
>   Developer Machine
>
> **-MySQL Server Config-**
>   port: 3306
>   windows service name: MySQL55
>   mysql root pass: root (you can change this later)
>   (username: root)
>   **-MySQL Server Config-**
>
> **--- for mySQL installation ---**

> **--- Install the mysql2 Gem ---**
>   Important: **Do this with Git Bash Command Line**(this was installed with railsinstaller) -> start/Git Bash
>   ***gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'***
>   
>   Now the gem should have installed correctly
>   
>   Lastly copy the libmysql.dll file from
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib
>   to
>   C:\Rails\Ruby1.9.2\bin
>   **--- Install the mysql2 Gem ---**

*You will now be able to use your Rails app with MySQL, if you are not sure how to create a Rails 3 app with MySQL read on...*

---

**--- Get a Rails 3 app going with MySQL ---**
Open command prompt(not Git Bash) -> start/cmd
Navigate to your  folder (c:\Sites)
Create new rails app

```
rails new world
```

Delete the file c:\Sites\world\public\index.html
Edit the file c:\Sites\world\config\routes.rb
add this line -> root :to => 'cities#index'

Open command prompt (generate views and controllers)

```
rails generate scaffold city ID:integer Name:string CountryCode:string District:string Population:integer
```

Edit the file c:\Sites\world\app\models\city.rb to look like this

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name "city"
end
```

Edit the file c:\Sites\world\config\database.yml to look like this

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: world
pool: 5
username: root
password: root
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Open **command prompt** windows cmd, not Git Bash(run your app!)
Navigate to your app folder (c:\Sites\world)

```
rails s
```

Open your browser here -> *http://localhost:3000*

**--- Get a Rails 3 app going with MySQL ---**

Comment: Gooooooooooooooooooooooood answer.

Comment: thanks! I struggled with the windows install for quite sometime :) git bash was the key for me

Answer (score 0):

> This is the command that works for me, make sure you use the full version of 1.7.3

```
gem install -v=0.2.7 mysql2 -- --with-mysql-include=C:\xampp\mysql\include --with-mysql-lib=C:\xampp\mysql\lib\opt --with-mysql-config=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql_config
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, even when I have the full version 1.7.4. install, but I simply do not have those folders

Comment: it only works on v1.7.3. on v1.7.4 it does not have these folders. and that was why i downgraded to v1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would update this for posterity. With the latest version of the rails installer for windows (as of the date of this post) and using Win 7, and I happen to have xampp installed here was my process. First run and install the rails installer. Now to install the mysql gem I did...

```
C:\Sites>gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.16 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\xam
pp\mysql
```

Note that in my configuration I am running xampp, hince I am passing the C:\xampp\mysql as the mysql dir path.

Next copy libmysql.dll from C:\xampp\mysql\lib to C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin. Now all the DB related to rails with hopfully 'just work' for you. For instance to create a new rails app with mysql do...

```
rails new the_next_facebook -d mysql
```

...and you should get your default config/database.yml file already setup to use mysql. Just make sure your username/pw are OK