# ruby mysql2 gem install error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am having problems installing mysql2 gem on my windows machine, usually it worked, but now I get `Failed to build native extension.` I googled around, but there were a lot of linux fixes. I know its not the best thing to work on windows with ruby. Back to the problem, I used `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin --with-mysql-lib=C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\lib` to install mysql2, it works with mysql, but rails requires mysql2.

Thank you.

Comment: refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836959/cant-install-mysql2-for-rails-3-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql2 can be tricky to install.  We JUST got a dev box working with Ruby 2.0.0p247, Windows 64bit and mysql 0.3.13. Here are some suggestions:

1. Make sure you have the latest DevKit installed (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). On the right column of the page, it tells you which version of the DevKit you'll need for your particular version of Ruby.  We've found it was easiest to install it to C:\DevKit
2. Now try and run the **gem install mysql2 ..**. command you listed in your question.  Alternatively, for 32bit installs we do:

```
subst X: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"
gem install mysql2 -v=0.3.13 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-include=X:\include --with-mysql-lib=X:\lib
subst X: /d
```

The **subst** command creates a virtual drive and helps with the spaces in the path name.

1. Copy the C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\libmysql.dll to your Ruby bin directory.  You should be off and running if you're working with 32bit.

64bit users however will likely run into another bug once they get mysql2 to build.  The above steps will appear to work, but when they actually go to use the mysql2 gem to do something useful, like run **rake db:create**, they get a segmentation fault.  More info and a fix for the issue can be found at https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/372, https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8591, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/uTNffOt6Yqo

Long story short, a compatible mysql connector c needs to be used instead of the MySQL server directory.  A helpful user provided the right connector c and it can be downloaded here (https://www.copy.com/s/CHZ4eT4us6f1/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64.zip).  Extract that zip file, and point your **gem install mysql2** ... command to the appropriate directories and 64bit happiness will follow.  (Don't forget to grab the libmysql.dll from the downloaded connector c folder and place it in your ruby bin directory).

Comment: This has worked for us on multiple machines now.  What is your specific error message?

Comment: I think you're missing '--' between --platform=ruby and --with-mysql-include, i.e. it should be gem install mysql2 -v=0.3.13 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-include=x:\include --with-mysql-lib=x:\lib

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command in command prompt.

**gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\lib\opt" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\include"'**

note: change the Mysql installation directory as per your installation.
That should work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Download the 32-bit Zip Archive of connector from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/). Then copy the extracted folder to the root of your C drive for ease of access so that your connector folder path will be something like this

```
C:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-win32\
```

Now copy this line of code to your cmd and execute (remember to change the connector version number with your one)

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:/mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-win32/"'
```

After trying for a long time I successfully installed mysql2 gem in both of my 32 and 64 bit windows 7 in this way. Cheers!