# mysql2 gem installation problems failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

so I've followed the instructions for a windows user here: [Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

yet i'm still getting an error. Here is what I'm typing (because i'm using mysql 5.6)

Here is a screen caption because i can't manage to copy the text:

[image: the GIT bash terminal]

Comment: try this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102523/ruby-mysql2-gem-install-error

Comment: @JetAbe tried that. now receiving this error at the gem install mysql2 command : ERROR: While executing gem.. (OptionParser::InvalidOption) Invalid option: --with-mysql-include=X:\include   ... followed the directions to a T

Comment: execute `/sbin/ldconfig` in mingw/sygwin shell, it shell be present in the installations